Microsoft Report Builder SSRS report Adding Editable text box report body
Microsoft Report Builder SSRS report Adding Editable text box report body
Hi, I am working on Microsoft report builder for creating SSRS report, I am new , I would like to add editable text box as Date, user want pick it up the date using the calendar before printing report.
Can anyone assist me how could I achieve this.

You can't do this, the only input you have in SSRS are parameters. Why not just have the date as a parameter and then have a textbox that shows the the value of the parameter? =Parameters!myDate.Value and change the textbox format to format the date as you require.
